# R 3.5 Installation Manjaro

Tags: r, linux, archlinux, manjaro

I'm trying to install R3.5 on my machine running Manjaro. If I try to update R from 3.4 to 3.5 pacman installs the new version but when I do

```
R --version
```

It tells me that I run R 3.4. Therefore I'm trying to unistall R and download the new ersion from the AUR but when I do

```
sudo pacman -R r
```

It tells me that it cannot find r. Tried also removing r-dev, r-dev-base but the package manager cannot find them.
Can someone please tell me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall package and then install by command

```
sudo pacman -S r
```